# Python kivy Android Gallery

Tags: python, android, kivy, kivy-language

I'm trying to save an image to the users android gallery below is my code, this code saves the image to their "Pictures" file inside file manager. How can I get it to save directly to their gallery?

Below is the code that I've tried!

.kv file

`

```
on_press: root.export_to_png("/sdcard/Pictures/Image.png")
```

`

Comment: Users have no gallery. Even an Android device has no gallery. An Android device can have so called Gallery apps which show all images in public storage locations.

Comment: The Pictures directory is not inside the/a file manager but part of public external storage.

Comment: @blackapps, I'm trying to save it to the gallery app.

Comment: @blackapps, you probably didn't understand what I was asking for. Every android device has a gallery location where if the user takes a picture with their phone they can view the picture in the gallery. That's where I'm trying to save the image.

Comment: There is no such thing as a gallery location. But as said before: apps can save image files to several public storage locations. Once done so they can wait until those files are indexed/scanned by the MediaStore. If that is done the so called Gallery apps can query the MediaStore for files and show them.